# import library in BigQuery through UDF

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I need to import the @google-cloud/bigquery library via UDF. But I've already tried to minify the webpack.config.js file but it is over 1.19MB, and BigQuery only accepts up to 1.04MB.

Any idea how to use this library inside BigQuery or how to reduce this size to 1.04MB?

Does anyone know if there is a native way to call this library directly in BigQuery without having to use webpack.config.js?

BigQuery Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery

Documentation through UDF: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-javascript-libraries

Comment: Could you clarify why you'd want to do this?  You can't interact with the API surface directly within a UDF, so it's unclear what value you'd get from the inclusion.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, as I couldn't execute a Query that was inside the function (using UDF with Javascript). When I called it, in SELECT, I was returned the Query text and not the results, which was what I wanted.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a stored procedure rather than a UDF.  Also, check out https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate